# How to redirect (301) multiple urls with the same path to on different domains in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have recently moved a domain to a new server and in the process have changed some urls. Old situation:

```
www.domain1.com/page-xyz.html
```

On the new server the same page can be seen under:

```
www.domain1.com/page-xyz/
```

In order to make sure that the old url redirects to the new one, I've added the following line to the .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /page-xyz.html http://www.domain1.com/page-xyz/
```

So far everything works as expected.
Now, I have moved a second domain (domain2.com) to the new server. Both domain1.com and domain2.com share the same directory.

On the old server of domain2.com there was also an url like this:

```
www.domain2.com/page-xyz.html
```

On the new server this page can be seen under:

```
www.domain2.com/page-xyz/
```

For this url I would like to add a 301 redirect as well. The problem is that with the redirect rule in place, the url `www.domain2.com/page-xyz.html` would be redirected to `http://www.domain1.com/page-xyz/`
How would I be able to create a redirect rule, with which the domain would be preserved?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove domain part from target URL:

```
Redirect 301 /page-xyz.html /page-xyz/
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

not tested but i think this will get you to the right path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
Redirect 301 page-xyz.html http://www.domain1.com/page-xyz/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$
Redirect 301 page-xyz.html http://www.domain2.com/page-xyz/
```